# how can i add and remove element dynamically from linear layout?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic-programming

```
LinearLayout linContact = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.linContacts);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftGravityparas = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);

for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
    final ClsAdviserData contact = .contactList.get(i);

    if (contact.isSelected()) {

        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linMainparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grey_backgeound));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linMainparam);
        linMainparam.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

        leftGravityparas.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        leftGravityparas.weight = 0.9f;
        TextView txtContact = new TextView(getActivity());
        txtContact.setTextSize(16);
        // txtContact.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grey_backgeound));
        txtContact.setLayoutParams(leftGravityparas);
        txtContact.setId(i);

        leftGravityparas.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

        txtContact.setPadding(20, 10, 10, 10);
        txtContact.setText(contact.getName());

        linearLayout.addView(txtContact, leftGravityparas);

        rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        rightGravityParams.weight = 0.1f;

        final ImageView imgDelContact = new ImageView(getActivity());

        imgDelContact.setLayoutParams(rightGravityParams);
        imgDelContact.setTag(i);
        imgDelContact.setClickable(true);
        imgDelContact.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgDelContact.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_grey);

        linearLayout.addView(imgDelContact, rightGravityParams);
        // linContact.setTag(i);
        linContact.addView(linearLayout);

        imgDelContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Toast ==>" + contact.getName() + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // linContact.removeViewAt((Integer) v.getTag());
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // lin.removeViewAt((Integer)v.getTag());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I wrote the above code to create the textfields and buttons dynamically; But now I need to remove 2 textfields and a button when the button is clicked. How do I do that?

Comment: [Dynamically Add and Remove Views using Java code](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding - 
After initializing add subview using addView() method declared in LinearLayout

```
linearLayout.addView(txtContact);
linearLayout.addView(imgDelContact);
```

Hide - 
To hide View ,so that you can get it again whenever required

```
imgDelContact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
txtContact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Remove - 
Or you can remove if you don't want to use it again.

```
linearLayout.removeView(txtContact);
linearLayout.removeView(imgDelContact);
```

Comment: @Gumbo if i need to use same View after removing it its better to Hide it.

Comment: @Archit please provide *Description why and where to use*.

Comment: @SilentKiller removing and adding will take more time to execute, but is more resource saving than hiding a view.

Comment: @Gumbo agreed that's why i added **if i need to use same View after removing it its better to Hide it**

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your response but i need some more help when i delete the last element that time it gives null pointer exception.

Comment: lin.removeViewAt((Integer)v.getTag());

Comment: @user3115082 i think you should use like this `lin.removeView(v);`

Answer (score 2):

To remove any view you can use

```
aLinearLayout.removeView(view)// to remove particular view
aLinearLayout.removeViewAt(position);// to remove view from particular position
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically creating views and you just need to remove all the views just use

`aLinearLayout.removeAllViews();`

This will clear the layout.